# Monotonic function without asymptote

Tags: asymptotics, monotone-functions

You know that $e^x$ has no vertical asymptote, but the horizontal asymptote 0; and that $\log(x)$ has no horizontal asymptote but vertical asymptote 0.

I was wondering, if there is a monotone unbounded continuously differentiable function in closed-form, which has no asymptote (not even an oblique one, so also no rotated hyperbola).

In particular, I was searching for a function with
$$f(x)< x\,\, \forall\, x \setminus \{0\},\\
f'(x)>0,\\
f''(x)<0$$
for all $x$, as well as $f(0)=0, f'(0)=1$.

The closest I got was this
$$ f(x)=\begin{cases}\log(x+1) &,x\ge0\\ 1-e^{-x} &,x<0\end{cases},$$
but this is not closed-form and has a discontinuous 3rd derivative. At first I thought that wouldn't be that difficult, but it's apparently harder than I thought... Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a monotone unbounded real-analytic function with no asymptotes, you might try $x^3$.

But if you want one that is concave, you might try

$$ f(x) = -{\frac {5\,{x}^{2}{{\rm e}^{-x}}}{16+16\,{{\rm e}^{-x}}}}+{\frac {x}{
\sqrt [4]{{x}^{2}+1}}}$$

Comment: Ah, sorry, I should have said concave ;). I see, that should do the trick. I will play around with this a little while. Thank you!